# Count visitors to website with php

Tags: php

I'm counting visitors to my website with a basic script:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_COOKIE['countedUser'])) {
    setcookie("countedUser", "0", time() + (86400 * 30));
    $countfile = fopen("counterfile.txt", "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");

    $new = intval(fgets($countfile)) + 1;

    fwrite($countfile, $new);
    fclose($countfile);
}

echo file_get_contents('counterfile.txt');
```

Counterfile contains the number 0

This works for going from 0 to 1, but it doesn't work after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are truncating `counterfile.txt` every time you open it:

> w+: Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file **and truncate the file to zero length**. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

[Source: the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Please note that you probably want to `flock()` your handle to prevent race conditions. (LOCK_EX = Exclusive Lock, LOCK_SH = Shared Lock)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely reason is that the `fgets($countfile)` always returns `NULL`.
And since `intval(NULL)` = `0`
Therefore, `$new++` never goes past 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized and increment by `1` when cookie doesn't exist. But, you didn't incremented when it exists.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['countedUser'])) 
{
  //initialize cookie
}
else
{
// increment current value
}
```

I'm assuming you would be aware of what cookie is

> ...small piece of data sent from a website and stored on ***the user's
>   computer by the user's web browser while the user is browsing.***